# Elasticsearch nested filter without results for specific attributed

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to apply a nested filter on a document but, for when I filter specifically by one of the nested attributes, I always get 0 results. For example, with a mapping like:

```
"PARTNER": {
   "properties": {
        "Addresses": {
             "properties": {
                    "CountyCode": {
                             "type": "string"
                    },
                    "EntityCode": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }, [...]
               }
        }, "type": "nested"
     }, [...]
}
```

I'm able to perform a filter on the CountyCode attribute, but if I filter on the EntityCode, i always get zero results:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "EntityCode": "201"
            }
          },
          "path": "Addresses"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That query gets zero results, if I replace the field with CountyCode, it gives me proper results. 
I'm performing the queries on the web-based console, on ES 1.4.2,.

The nested documents have the format:

```
{
    "CountyCode": "516",
    "EntityCode": "203",
    [...]
}
```

Any idea on why that one field returns nothing ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `"type": "nested"` declaration is in the wrong place. It should be inside the `"Addresses"` block. You probably also need to specify the full path in your `"nested"` filter (though sometimes ES is smart enough to work without doing that, if there aren't too many nested fields).

So to test, I created an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "PARTNER": {
         "properties": {
            "Addresses": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "CountyCode": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "EntityCode": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then added a couple docs:

```
POST /test_index/PARTNER/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"Addresses":[{"CountyCode": "516","EntityCode": "203"}, {"CountyCode": "516","EntityCode": "201"}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"Addresses":[{"CountyCode": "517","EntityCode": "204"}]}
```

And now the following query returns what I expect:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "Addresses",
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "Addresses.EntityCode": "201"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "PARTNER",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "Addresses": [
                  {
                     "CountyCode": "516",
                     "EntityCode": "203"
                  },
                  {
                     "CountyCode": "516",
                     "EntityCode": "201"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is all the code I used to test:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d677144a58b168d46c5d7e9cc516013b20613013

Comment: Hi Sloan. The mapping was "hand-made" just to simplify the problem, the nested type definition is indeed an attribute of Addresses. Anyway, what I was missing was really the full path on the actual filter (I have another EntityCode on a different nested filter, but no other CountyCode, so that should be the reason why the behaviour was different). Thank you!